# Generics implementation using interface with generics

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I have an interface Value and a class Record

```
public interface Value<T> {
    T getRawValue();
}

public class Record<Value<T>> {

    private Value<T> value;     

    T getRecordRawValue() {
        return value.getRawValue();
    }

}
```

Java will not compile this and complains about the Generics declaration > . Could someone enlighten me as to why this is invalid syntax?

Answer (score 7):

You need  bound your generic type to indicate the requirement of it being a `Value<T>`, and you also need to preserve the type that value `Value<T>` is providing, therefore your  `Record` class requires two generic types: T: The type of the values returned and U: the type that represents a `Value<T>`

`public class Record<T, U extends Value<T>>`

Here you have a full example of this:

```
public interface Value<T> {
    T getRawValue();
}

public class Record<T, U extends Value<T>> {

    public Record(U value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private U value;

    T getRecordRawValue() {
        return value.getRawValue();
    }

}

public class StringValue implements Value<String> {

    @Override
    public String getRawValue() {
        return "raw";
    }
}

public class StrongValue implements Value<String> {

    @Override
    public String getRawValue() {
        return "Rrrrraaawww";
    }
}

public class StringRecord extends Record<String, StringValue> {

    public StringRecord(StringValue valueProvider) {
        super(valueProvider);
    }

    public String report() {
        return super.getRecordRawValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 The recursive type parameter doesn't make sense here. It should either be `Record<T>` or `Record<T extends Value<V>, V>`.

Comment: @PaulBellora  you are right. This will make the type of the 'getRecordValue' of Value<T> and not  <T> what is the goal of the question. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Looks pretty good - I think you have `T` and `U` backwards in `Record` though.

Comment: @PaulBellora  oops :-) I changed that to match the explanatory text and forgot to do it everywhere :-)

Answer (score 2):

The code `public class Record<Value<T>>` attempts to declare a generic type parameter for the class called `Value<T>`, but when declaring a generic type parameter, it should be a simple identifier such as `T`.

Try

```
public class Record<T>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I am trying to do is be able to use record like

    new Record<Value<Long>>()

Comment: So, you can do `new Record<Long>()`. Does the client have to know that inside you are using `Value<T>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Record` class is wrongly declared. It should be

```
public class Record<T> {
    //contents...
}
```